# DBMS and View optimization

Tags: android, optimization, database

is it true that a DBMS can optimize the access to a View by performing the query that defines the View only when the data that is backing the View is modified and not everytime I query the View itself?

**EDIT**
What about SQLite for Android?

Comment: DBMS? Any in particular this is (probably) database specific.

Comment: the question is about a generic DBMS: whether or not that is a common feature

Answer (score 0):

Delamere,

The answer to your question depends largely on your implementation of the Views, the Database queries, and the underlying structure. In essence, the core issue is the nature of the data and how often it *needs* to be requeried.

In some of my published apps, I have data that only needs to be queried whenever the Window receives focus. In these cases, a simple manual refresh is called. These are often atomic queries meaning they are miniscule amounts of data. Using this method, I've bridged many apps and their data together into a cohesive almost instantaneous query.

In other cases, the data changes quite often but predictably. In these cases, it is counter-productive to reduce the number of queries, but it is also ineffectual to bind an observer.

Finally, there are several cases where the data will change irregularly and the amount of change is unpredictable. In these cases, the optimal solution is to utilize an Observer. This will make sure that only the queries that need to run are run. And the views will be updated as soon as the adapter is updated.

In reference to your question, the final scenario (I think) conveys what you are asking. In short, the answer is yes.... ***but... *** refer to the first two scenarios. To decide on the optimal solution for yourself, you need to have the answers to the following:

1. How much data are you querying at any given time?
2. How often will that data change?
3. Could it change while your app is running?

Once you have the answers to those questions, you may align your solution accordingly. Without more information, this is the extent of the guidance you will probably receive. I would also strongly advise that if you aren't familiar with basic database engineering concepts, that you familiarize yourself with the concepts of normalization, relational models, and indexing. A strong understanding of these can greatly improve the performance of your database, your app and the appropriate Views.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic